# Is it possible to run a background thread when my app was closed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, notifications

I want some operations to be performed in background when my app was closed. is it possible in ios

Comment: Please specify what you mean by "closed".

Comment: I mean i wnt keep it in background i will completely close my app.

Comment: How do you close the app? There are several ways to do this and the answer is different.

Comment: even if the user terminates the app. i want some operations to be performed in background from os side is it possible ?

Comment: I have clarified my answer, see below. NO application will survive if you kill it.

Comment: Please edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer; **YES** it is possible to have an application running in the background.

If you close the application by pressing the home button, the application is "freezed" unless you specify it should run in the background. But there are some limitations, see my explanation below.

If you kill the application, it is not possible for it to run in the background. No application will survive when you kill it. Killing is done like this; double-click the home button and then long press the application. Finally you press the application. This will kill the application.

The biggest limitation is that your application needs to be of certain type, otherwise it is not allowed to execute in the background. This is specified in the *Info.plist* file. Specifically you need to add the *UIBackgroundModes* in the *Info.plist* file. If it another type of application and try to run in the background, the application will be rejected for publishing in Appstore.

These are the types of applications that are allowed to execute in the background:

- Audio applications
- Location applications
- VoIP applications
- Newsstands applications
- Applications that polls external accessories

Then there are certain rules that the application needs to follow certain rules. Everything is explained [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW3).